# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to calculate the limit, using L'Hospital's Rule.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)$$

---

**My attempt**

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x^2 - \sin^2(x))'}{(x^2\sin^2(x))'} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x - \sin(2x)}{2x\sin^2(x) +x^2\sin(2x)}  $$

I stopped trying at that point because the limit seems to get overly complicated and I run out of other ideas. Any tips on how to solve this?

***Extra side-note question:** I generally stuggle when I try to solve limits that involve infinity with trigonometrics. Is there a general rule to reduce these problems into easier ones?*

Comment: Dividing everything with $2x$ will probably work. I just found out. Anyways, still looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Derivative of $\sin^{2}(x)$ is $2\sin x \cos x=\sin (2x)$. how did you get $x^{2} \sin (2x)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My bad, I am editing, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you mean $x\to\infty$ rather than $x\to0$? If so, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, take a look at the denominator after the first step.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist, 
BTW @Veriun why did you differentiate?

Comment: @Zuy What's up with the denominator?

Comment: @VenkatAmith I attempted to L'Hopital it. It doesn't exists because of the sin(x)'s going inf?

Comment: @J.G. I am sure yes, $x\to \infty$

Comment: There's no limit as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Why do you use Hopital's rule: you have not $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ or $\text{something}/\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limit cannot exist because $\sin (\infty)$ bounded but uncertain real number.
Take two sequences $x_n=n\pi, x'_n=(n+1/2)\pi$ such that bot $x_n$ and $x_n$ tend to $\infty$.  As $n \to \infty$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$ attains two unequal values: $f(x_n)=\infty$ and $f(x'_n)=1,$ the limit does not exist.